# Is it not possible to use FeatureManagment.checkPermission inside a package manage for a custom permission which is not included in that package

Tags: feature-management

I have tried accessing the value inside the package, but the `FeatureManagement.checkPermission()` is returning false, whereas when the same Function is executed anonymously It returns true, indicating the the custom permission is assigned either to the current logged in user profile/permission set.

So can any one provide a workaround for accessing the custom permission value inside a managed package.

Answer (score 1):

Query it using SOQL:

```
SELECT Id, CustomPermissionId, SetupEntityId
FROM CustomPermissionDependency
WHERE CustomPermission.DeveloperName = 'Your_Custom_Permission_Name'
AND SetupEntityId = 'UserOrProfileId'
```